# What is x-axis in variable importance in R?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am using package `caret` in R to measure variable importance of random forest model.

My question is, what is the X-axis of the importance plot `caret` provided? An example could be found at http://topepo.github.io/caret/varimp.html, at the bottom of the web page. The X-axis range from 0 to 20, but what does it mean?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It looks to be a combination of the importance functions from the RandomForest and party packages, Partial Least Squares and Recursive Partitioning. More info here under Details when going down to Random Forest.

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/varimp